# extend emmet-vim to works in javascript (js) type files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vim

How can I extend emmet-vim, so that it also works in javascript (js) type files, for example, used for react components? According to the current settings in vimrc, emmet-vim only works in HTML, CSS, and jsx files. Thank you.

It's weird when I add php in my line `autocmd FileType html, css, javascript, php EmmetInstall` emmet-vim is working in a PHP file type, but not in a js file type.

Works only with `: set filetype:javascript.jsx`.

Comment: What does `set filetype?` say when you edit your javascript files?

Comment: Please share the relevant lines from your `vimrc`. You should just be able to add `javascript` to the list of supported filetypes.

Comment: @svlasov for `set filetype?` I get `filetype=javascript`

Comment: @Friedrich What I add to my vimrc: `let g:user_emmet_settings = {
  \  'javascript.jsx' : {
    \      'extends' : 'jsx',
    \  },
  \}

autocmd FileType html, js, css,javascript.jsx EmmetInstall
`

Comment: Did you try to follow README: `autocmd FileType html,css,javascript EmmetInstall`

Comment: @svlasov Yes. Do not work.

Comment: There must be no whitespace behind the commas separating the filetypes. Also remove the invalid ones. Use `:set verbose=9` as suggested by `:help autocommand`.

Comment: @Friedrich, `javascript.jsx` is valid.